# How to reference columns by name based on comma separated value in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
PartNumber    Part    ValuesList    x1    x2    x3    x4
123456        Fender  x1            11    10    9     12
123456        Fender  x1,x2         11    10    9     12
123456        Fender  x2,x4         11    10    9     12
123456        Fender  x1,x2,x3,x4   11    10    11    12
123456        Fender  x2,x3,x4      11    10    9     12
```

For each row, how can I find the lowest value from columns x1, x2, x3, x4 based on the column names given in ValuesList?

For example, row 1 is easy. The ValuesList value is x1, so I only need to look at column x1 and the lowest value is 11.

Row 2 .. the ValuesList values are x1,x2. I need the lower number between columns x1 and x2 (11 and 10). The lowest value is 10.

Row 3 .. the ValuesList values are x2,x4. I need the lower number between colums x2 and x4 (10 and 12). The lowest value is 10.

Row 4 .. the ValuesList values are x1,x2,x3,x4. I need the lower number between columns x1, x2, x3 and x4 (11, 10, 11, 12). The lowest value would be 10.

Row 5 .. the ValuesList values are x2,x3,x4. I need the lower number between columns x2, x3 and x4 (10, 9, 12). The lowest value would be 9.

The actual table has hundreds of thousands of rows.

In pseudocode, I would want something like

```
SELECT PartNumber, Part, MIN(ColumnValue) WHERE ColumnName IN (SELECT ColumnNames FROM ValuesList)
```

In the case where the lowest number appears in multiple columns, it doesn't matter which column the lowest number is taken from.

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you should be fixing your design; storing delimited data in your RDBMS is always a flaw. So too is storing multiple columns with the same name, just incremented (in this case `x1`, `x2`, etc). If you fix your design, this is *very* easy. Just a couple `JOIN`s and an aggregate function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to *assume* you are using a recent version of SQL Server here, and thus have access to `STRING_SPLIT`. If not, then you'll need to use a user defined string splitter; there are plenty out there if you do a search (though I recommend using a set based one). Then, along side `STRING_SPLIT` you can unpivot your data, I use a table `VALUES` construct for that, implicitly `JOIN` in the `WHERE` and finally aggregate:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (PartNumber int,
                            Part varchar(10),
                            ValuesList varchar(8000),
                            x1 int,
                            x2 int,
                            x3 int,
                            x4 int);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES(123456,'Fender','x1         ',11,10,9 ,12),
      (123456,'Fender','x1,x2      ',11,10,9 ,12),
      (123456,'Fender','x2,x4      ',11,10,9 ,12),
      (123456,'Fender','x1,x2,x3,x4',11,10,11,12),
      (123456,'Fender','x2,x3,x4   ',11,10,9 ,12);
GO

SELECT YT.PartNumber,
       YT.Part,
       YT.ValuesList,
       MIN(V.XVal) AS MinX
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(YT.ValuesList,',') SS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(N'x1',x1),
                        (N'x2',x2),
                        (N'x3',x3),
                        (N'x4',x4))V(XCol,XVal)
WHERE SS.[value] = V.XCol
GROUP BY YT.PartNumber,
         YT.Part,
         YT.ValuesList;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Of course, I really suggest you normalise your design here. Don't store delimited data, and don't repeat column values. If you normalise your design you'll likely just need a couple of `JOIN`s and an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Select A.PartNumber
      ,A.Part
      ,A.ValuesList
      ,B.MinValue 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select MinValue=min(Value)
                From  (values (case when charindex('x1',ValuesList)>0 then x1 end)
                             ,(case when charindex('x2',ValuesList)>0 then x2 end)
                             ,(case when charindex('x3',ValuesList)>0 then x3 end)
                             ,(case when charindex('x4',ValuesList)>0 then x4 end)
                      ) B1(Value)
             )B
```

**Results**

```
PartNumber  Part    ValuesList  MinValue
123456      Fender  x1          11
123456      Fender  x1,x2       10
123456      Fender  x1,x2,x3,x4 10
123456      Fender  x2,x3,x4    9
123456      Fender  x2,x4       10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend doing this without an outer `group by`:

```
SELECT t.*, s.min_val
FROM t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT MIN(val) as min_val
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(YT.ValuesList,',') s JOIN
           (VALUES('x1', x1), ('x2', x2), ('x3', x3),('x4', x4)
           )v(col, val)
           ON s.value = v.name
     ) s;
```

Using `APPLY` on values *within* a row usually has much better performance characteristics than aggregating over an entire data set.